# Python JSON - Elasticsearch - [_na] query malformed, must start with start_object

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, post, python-requests

I am trying to duplicate the following json params in a Python post request:

[image]

This is what I have in my dictionary:

```
payload = {
           'match':{'situs.state':'AL'},
           'notMatch':{},
           'page':1,
           'range':{
                   'loanAmount':[
                                 {
                                  'gte':None,
                                  'lte':10000000
                                 }
                                ]
                    },
            'size':100
          }
```

I then pass this dictionary into my post request with json.dumps so it gets converted to json and sent with the post request.

> data = json.dumps(payload)

However, nothing works as I get the following error:

> {"type":"Elasticsearch","message":"[parsing_exception] [_na] query
>   malformed, must start with start_object, with { line=1 & col=119
>   }","path":"/some_path","query":{"size":100,"from":0},"statusCode":400,"body":{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[_na]
>   query malformed, must start with
>   start_object","line":1,"col":119}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[_na]
>   query malformed, must start with
>   start_object","line":1,"col":119},"status":400}}

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `0` should be `gte` and `1` should be `lte`

Comment: I am new to json. I just quickly checked out what gte and lte are. After replacing them (I've also editted my initial post to reflect the changes) and running the code again, I now get :"type":   "parsing_exception","reason":"[range] query doesn't support multiple fields, found [loanAmount] and [lte]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range part should be like this:

```
     'range':{
          'loanAmount':{
              'gte':None,
              'lte':10000000
          }
     },
```

Comment: After looking around I saw that its just as you said. I was passing two arguments instead of one. However, I need loanAmount to remain as an array and not a dict. Running the code with loanAmount as an dictionary crashes with a TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'. I've revised my code to reflect the changes and my new error.

Comment: Aside from that your payload is just not a valid DSL query. `notMatch` and `page` are not valid and `match` and `range` need to be inside a `bool` query. I'm not sure how you came to that query format

Comment: I came to that query format from not knowing anything about Elasticsearch, like literally nothing. I thought I just had to replicate plain json with my post request. I wasn't aware there was a specific format I had to follow. That explains a lot! Well, I guess I'm off to learn exactly what Elasticsearch is and how to write a proper query. Thanks @Val!